# How to remove legend being taken as a dimension in python plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

So I wish to Plot the pairwise scatter plot with hue dimension of the grid.

But legend which is `:1` and `:2` is also getting displayed along other labels.I guess it is taking 1 and 2 as numbers not as legend strings.

Here is my code:

```
plt.close();
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
x = sns.pairplot(data, hue="status", height=2.5);

plt.show()
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image: My output]

I wish to remove status being taken as a dimension

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want all the variables to be plotted, you should specify which ones you want. That is done with the [vars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) argument:

```py
x = sns.pairplot(data, vars=['age', 'years', 'nodes'], hue="status", height=2.5);
plt.show()
```